# How to find Logstash is at EOF?

Tags: bash, eof, logstash

I am using Logstash with ElasticSearch to analyze and store data out of my apache logs. In my setup logstash is taking input from a file `stdin.log`.

I want to create a script which automatically insert latest logs into `stdin.log` when ever logstash have reached at the end of `stdin.log`. So my question is that is there a way to find whether logstash has reached to eof or not? Can I use sincedb file for this purpose?

Comment: But why `stdin.log`? You can just make `logstash` process read from Apache `error.og/access.log` files.

Comment: @anubhava I have to read from multiple apache logs files from multiple locations. My script will download them to local system.

Comment: These multiple locations are on same host?

Comment: No. I forgot to add multiple apache logs files from multiple remote locations.

Comment: How about a shipper on each remote host?  logstash-forwarder, beaver, etc...

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's caught up? If this is to make sure that all systems have logs complete through a given time period, I'd do that by creating a sigil on each machine -- do any request across your whole pool, wait until that request is indexed in ElasticSearch, and you're done. That's safer than looking at where the file pointers are, anyhow, since looking at the file pointers tells you content has been read, but not that it's been _processed_ and is ready for retrieval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have achieved my goal by comparing size of file with offset provided in sincedb file.

```
currentPosition = tail -1 .sincedb | awk '{printf $4}'
```

yields current offset of file logstash's file pointer in logfile. While

```
fileSize = stat  -c '%s' stdin.log
```

yields total size in bytes. So comparing it

```
if[[ $currentPosition = $fileSize ]]; then #Proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look inside the sincedb file to get the inodes and current offsets.

Comment: I don't think that sincedb is a sqlite database. It plain text file containing inode, device id, source id and offset in plain text format delimited by spaces.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Looks like it was beaver's file that was maintained with sqlite.  I've edited the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `lsof -oo10 -p $LOGSTASHPID` and examine the OFFSET column for the file in question